# Colors in elsarticle

Tags: color, elsarticle

I'm trying to change the document class of my article which has been accepted in an Elsevier paper to `elsarticle`. Everything seems mostly ok, except all the cell colors in the tables I have no longer work.

In particular, things like `\rowcolor{gray!60}` and `\cellcolor{red!70}` no longer work, they simply yield cells which are completely black. I am currently using `\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}`. I have no idea what interactions are breaking this.

Comment: With the information you provided so far, I can not reproduce the output you get. Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue. Do you get any error messages? If so, which?

Comment: If I try to build a MWE with the information already present in the question, I end up with a code like `\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\rowcolor{gray!60}text & text \\
text & \cellcolor{red!70}text \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}` which compiles perfectly fine and results in the expected output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBGtb.png with correctly colored cells.

Comment: Ended up being the diagbox package which was breaking it. As I was only using it once I'll just change that!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by the OP (see comments).